# AngularJS ui-router: Test ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to test some views, that are using `<a ui-sref='someState'>link</a>` to link to other states in my application. In my tests I'm triggering a click on this elements like this:

```
element.find('a').click()
```

How do I test, if the state is switched to `someState`? It would be easy, when using `$state` in my controller like this:

```
// in my view
<a ng-click="goTo('someState')">link</a>

// in my controller
$scope.goTo = function(s) {
  $state.go(s)
};

// in my tests
spyOn($state, 'go');
element.find('a').click()
expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

But when I use `ui-sref` I don't know what object to spy on. How can I verify, that my application is in the right state?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found it myself. After having a look into the angular ui router source code, I found this line inside the `ui-sref` directive:

```
// angular-ui-router.js#2939
element.bind("click", function(e) {
  var button = e.which || e.button;
  if ( !(button > 1 || e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey || e.shiftKey || element.attr('target')) ) {
    // HACK: This is to allow ng-clicks to be processed before the transition is initiated:
    $timeout(function() {
      $state.go(ref.state, params, options);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

When the element receives a click, the `$state.go` is wrapped in a `$timout` callback. So, in your tests, you have to inject the `$timeout` module. Then just do a `$timeout.flush()` like this:

```
element.find('a').click();
$timeout.flush();
expect($state.is('someState')).toBe(true);
```

Comment: Wow, didn't expect this.  `$timeout.flush()` fixes this for the test but you have to remember to do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
[...]
element.find('a').click()
expect($state.is('someState')).toBe(true)
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this doesn't seem to work, when I look into `$state.current` the state doesn't switch. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use $rootScope.$apply() in order to have the state change.