# How can I trigger ui-sref in an AngularJS unit test?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I'm testing an AngularJS view. There are a few non-standard helpers in this code sample, but hopefully it will get the point across. I'm fairly certain none of them are interfering with the function in question.

Here's the view (in Jade):

```
#authentication-options
  button#sign-up(ui-sref='sign-up') Create an Account
  a#sign-in(ui-sref='sign-in') I already have an account.
```

And the spec:

```
spec 'AuthenticationOptions', ->
  beforeEach ->
    @view = $view 'authentication-options.html'

  describe 'elements', ->
    describe 'sign up button', ->
      beforeEach ->
        @button = findSelector 'button#sign-up', in: @view

      it 'exists', ->
        expectElement @button

      # I would expect to be able to test this using
      # `triggerHandler`, but it doesn't work.
      it 'transitions to sign up when clicked', ->
        # @button is the #sign-up button node wrapped with angular.element.

        @button.triggerHandler('click')
        get('$rootScope').$digest()
        expect(get('$state').current.name).to.eq 'sign-up'
```

This works in the browser but the spec does not change the state. (I receive: `AssertionError: expected 'authentication-options' to equal 'sign-up'`)

The whole module, including `ui-router` and configured states, is all loaded.

Is there another event I should be firing here, or some other method to test the behavior of this button in a unit/integration test rather than a full-blown E2E?

Comment: You don't test single units anymore but their interoperation (the link above confirms this). Which can be also tricky and differ from what you see in browser, so you may end up testing the same thing twice. I would save dom testing for e2e/integration, at least for such complex scenarios.

Comment: It's a good point @estus. I find when working with Angular in a BDD style, the lines between E2E and unit testing blur quickly. I'm not exactly testing the DOM, since I'm working completely through the $compile service. I'm testing the state of the Angular app and assuming that the DOM will behave properly. This is definitely not a unit test, but it's significantly faster than an E2E and allows behavior-driven testing of things like forms which may have a boatload of logical forks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need `$timeout.flush();` after you do `@button.triggerHandler('click')`.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25503524/5246